# Jersey REST service with Spring Boot throwing an exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: validation, spring-boot, jersey

I have a spring boot application with a jersey REST service. When I deploying my war file in standalone jetty, it throws an exception as shown below

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Configuration.getBootstrapConfiguration()Ljavax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration;
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationBinder$ConfiguredValidatorProvider.getTraversableResolver(ValidationBinder.java:322)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationBinder$ConfiguredValidatorProvider.getDefaultValidatorContext(ValidationBinder.java:303)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationBinder$ConfiguredValidatorProvider.getDefaultValidator(ValidationBinder.java:282)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationBinder$ConfiguredValidatorProvider.provide(ValidationBinder.java:225)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationBinder$ConfiguredValidatorProvider.provide(ValidationBinder.java:195)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.create(FactoryCreator.java:153)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:70)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2020)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:766)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getUnqualifiedService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:773)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.IterableProviderImpl.get(IterableProviderImpl.java:111)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker$Builder.build(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:153)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RuntimeModelBuilder.createInflector(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:128)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RuntimeModelBuilder.createMethodRouter(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:115)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RuntimeModelBuilder.createResourceMethodRouters(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:309)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RuntimeModelBuilder.buildModel(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:173)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.Routing$Builder.buildStage(Routing.java:196)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:587)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:640)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:419)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:875)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1404)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:520)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:411)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:378)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1516)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1441)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
```

Here is my POM.xml file

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId> 
            <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core" -->
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JPA Provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Trying to understand where that javax.validation is coming from, as I see `validation-api-1.1.0-final.jar` and `hibernate-validator-5.2.4-final.jar` both of these jars in my war file.

[image: Hibernate-validator]
[image: validation-api]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is ideal, but I resolved this issue by

```
                 <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
```

from my dependency of `spring-boot-starter-jersey`

Answer (score 2):

So your Jetty requires javax validation-api in version 1.1 (or newer) and you already know that. Some other library is actually attaching a transitive dependency to a different (older) version of validation-api. Your version of Hibernate-Validator (5.2.4) uses Validator-Api 1.1.0 ([see here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final)).

Since you are using Maven, then it would be best to use [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) to see full dependency tree and track it manually.

Comment: I am not understanding which one to keep. I can see spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-jersey are bringing those conflicting jars.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put a full output of the Maven Dependency Plugin?  You can use http://pastebin.com/ if it is too bit to put on SO.

Comment: Sorry I am using eclipse ...how can I get that in eclipse?

Comment: I added screenshots

Comment: If I remove maven dependency of spring-boot-starter-jersey, i don't run into this issue. I don't know what else to try with this, if I don't use spring-boot-starter-jersey, I am not able to connect spring and jersey.